# Matplotlib plot not showing with plt.ion() in a python script, but working in python shell

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am trying to get an interactive matplotlib plot to run. From the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#interactive-example) I tried this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])
```

If I copy it into a shell everything works fine and a window opens.
But if I try to execute the code in a script with `python3 script.py` after a second it returns back to the shell without showing any window.

It seems that this seems be a popular problem, but no solution I found on the internet was working.

I tried adding `plt.show()` and `plt.draw()`, as well a loop so that the program does not immediately exit. But then there is just the python rocket bouncing in my doc indefinitely.

I tried different backends, but the symptoms where the same for all of them.

I installed python3 using homebrew and matplotlib using pip3. I run macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: The trick is to understand what each of the available tools do, then use the most suitable one. The answers to your current question appear to be guess-and-check while the ones in the linked question have more substantive explanations based on an actual understanding of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

It works fine for my case.

Comment: this shows the window, but seems to 'disable' interactive mode, as I cannot update data in the window in a loop afterwards. Unfortunately not a real solution to me :(

Comment: That's because you need to show the window after you've finished the updates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the python debugging module to do this.

Use `plt.ion()` before you start plotting.

Then add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the point you want to start working interactively.

I use this method a lot for playing around with a complex plot until I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to run, by adding `plt.pause(0.25)` in my loop to update the data, so that my final code would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
plt.ion()
plt.plot([0, 1])

for i in range(50):
    print(i)
    plt.scatter(random.random(), random.random())
    plt.pause(0.25)
```

I don't understand why the pause is necessary, but maybe it helps someone else who is struggling.

Comment: The pause is there to show the order of adding a datapoint. Outside and it will be shown only for 0.25s... kinda short ;-) and you should use `plt.show(block=True)` to keep is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of answers from users Pei Li and OP plasmoctopus, but with a twist and remarks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])

for i in range(50):
    print(i)
    plt.scatter(random.random(), random.random())
    plt.pause(0.25)  # adds each datapoint to the graph slowly but visible. 
                     # Remove this to show the graph instantly once its constructed.

plt.show(block=True)  # this keeps the graph result shown. Close it manually.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, add user input to keep the plot window until you enter something in the terminal

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6,2.7])
input('> hit return to dismiss plot')
```

Or use `plt.waitforbuttonpress` to display plot until the plot window is clicked

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6,2.7])
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```